# How to collect a list of latitude and longitude data for a location dataframe?

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, geospatial, geopy

I recently started coding in Python. I'm importing a csv file containing around 848 unique locations across India, and would like to use the [geopy module](https://pypi.org/project/geopy/) to add in latitude and longitude for each location. After importing the data, I used this code:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("../project/LocationIndia.csv")

lat = []
long = []

for location in df["Location"]:
    # Initialize Nominatim API
    address = location + ', India'
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="MyApp")
    location = geolocator.geocode(address)
    lat.append(location.latitude)
    long.append(location.longitude)

df['latitude']=latitude
df['longitude']=longitude
df
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [14], in <cell line: 4>()
      7     geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="MyApp")
      8     location = geolocator.geocode(address)
----> 9     lat.append(location.latitude)
     10     long.append(location.longitude)
     11 df['latitude']=latitude

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'latitude'
```

Not sure why this is happening. If anyone can help me out, would be great, thanks!

This is the table btw:

```
    Location
0   Kharghar
1   Sector-13 Kharghar
2   Sector 18 Kharghar
3   Sector 20 Kharghar
4   Sector 15 Kharghar
... ...
843 BTM Layout
844 Kuvempu Layout on Hennur Main Road
845 Marathahalli
846 Rajajinagar
847 RMV
```

I was expecting values to be inputted as columns in the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

[geolocator.geocode()](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html?highlight=geolocator#module-geopy.geocoders) returns `None`, if no results are found. Try error handling like:

```
if location is not None:
    # your code here
```